# On submit, save into SESSION and send this SESSION to a new php page

Tags: php, session

Here is my code. This is in the login page.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}

<form action="BAMainPage.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" id="login" onclick="loginfunction()" >Log In</button>
    <script>
    function loginfunction() {
        if(document.getElementById('username').value!=="") {    
            //location.href="http://localhost/bhbonlineretailphp/BAMainPage.php";                           
        } else {
            alert("failed");
        }                      
    }
    </script>
</form>
```

This is the BAMainPage that opens, after the login button is clicked.

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

However, on opening, the BAMainPage shows this error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\BHBOnlineRetailPHP\BAMainPage.php
```

Why is the username not defined? I've already saved the value into `$_SESSION['username']`.

Comment: You only save the value to session when `$_POST['username']` is set, but by the looks of it, your form directs to a different file so that code won't run anyway. There's also the problem that you don't seem to have an input that define `username` anyway, making the first point moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are posting your username to BAMainPage.php that means that you need to assign the username from the POST there and not in the same file you are submitting the form from

so just move

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    }
```

to BAMainPage and then echo it and you hsould be able to see it, from there on you can continue the session somewhere else and the `$SESSION['username ']` will follow you

Comment: OMG It works! Thanks!! hahah I've spent 2 hours on this and cant seem to solve this problem. One more question, does this mean that my action brings my POST to the next page instead? Therefore i have to call out the POST in the next page?

Comment: yes, but you can specify the action as POST the form to the same page as you are like this
 action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>

Comment: no problem contact me at my github account github.com/rojobo

Answer (score 0):

Earlier on it's not getting your $_POST['username'].

Your login action is BAMainPage.php. So, as soon as you get your form POST data here, you should write the session in this page instead of writing it in the previous page.

```
// BAMainPage.php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}
```

After that you can write:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

In any page you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Assuming you just forgot to include some form elements in the posted code...]

This code never executes:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

Because you never post the form to that page.  You post it to a different page:

```
<form action="BAMainPage.php" method="post">
```

So on `BAMainPage.php` is where you would access `$_POST['username']`.  Basically, you don't need to use session state at all in this interaction.  The form values are directly sent to `BAMainPage.php`.